# Can this sequence be a martingale?

Tags: martingales, conditional-expectation

Consider the following sequence of random variables:

$X_1$ has only values $0$ and $1$ with positive probability

$X_2$ only $0,1,2$

$X_3$ only $0,1,2,3$.

Let's stop here. Can this sequence be a martingale?

We would need to find out what $\mathbb{E}(X_2|X_1)$ is.

But I do not see how we could say anything about this without knowing the distribution of those variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need to say whether it *can* be a martingale. Obviously, you do not know enough information to say it *is* a martingale.

In this situation you should provide an example to show that it can be a martingale, or present a proof that it cannot possibly be one.

So:

For $n \geq 1$, Let $X_{n+1} = 0$ if $X_n = 0$ with probability $1^*$.

Otherwise, let $X_{n+1} = X_n - 1$ with probability $1/3$,  $X_n$ with probability $1/3$ and $X_n+1$ with probability $1/3$.

Then $\{X_n\}$ is a martingale.

[* You might ask "Why can we do this: the question states that $X_n$ has values $0, \dots, n$ with positive probabilities?" The answer is, we can still make it such that the marginal distribution has a positive probability for each state. It is my interpretation that this is allowed. If the conditional distributions must also have positive probabilities for all states then the answer is no, it cannot be a martingale.]

Comment: Probably I'm missing something obvious: By assumption, $X_1$ does not equal $0$ with probability $1$, so we are in the "otherwise"-case. But then $X_2$ takes also the value $-1$ with probability $>0$, doesn't it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a few questions. If $X_1$ has only values $0,1$, how can $X_2$ be equal $X_1-1$ with probability $1/3$?

Comment: I haven't actually assigned a distribution to $X_1$. If you look again, I only assigned distributions for $X_2$ and onwards. It doesn't matter what distribution you give to $X_1$ because it is the initial state and so there is no requirement which says "$\mathbb{E}[X_1|X_0] = X_0$".

Comment: @Walter But the OP assumes that $X_1$ *has* an assigned distribution; namely, that is takes (only) values $0$ and $1$ with probability $>0$.

Comment: Regardless of how $X_1$ is distributed, if the distributions of $X_2, X_3, \dots$ are defined as above, then $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^N$ is a martingale.

Comment: Sure, but $X_2$ takes negative values with probability $>0$. I don't get it.

Comment: If $X_1 = 0$ then $X_2 = 0$ with certainty, as I stated.

Comment: So if we have $X_1$ with values $0,1$ with probabilities $1/2,1/2$, then $X_2$ has values $0,1,2$ with probabilities $1/2,1/4,1/4$, $X_3$ has values $0,1,2,3$ with prob $1/2,1/6,1/6,1/6$?

Comment: $X_2$ has values $0,1,2$ with probabilities $2/3, 1/6$ and $ 1/6$ and $X_3$ has values $0,1,2,3$ with probabilities $13/18, 1/9,1/9, 1/18$.

Comment: @Walter Could you explain to me with more details what we should do with zeros? Why and how does the probability of $X_n=0$ change?

Comment: $0$ is an absorbing state.

Comment: @Walter So if $P(X_1=0)= 1/2, P(X_1=1)=1/2$, then $P(X_2=0) = 1/2+1/6, P(X_2=1)=1/6, P(X_2=2)=1/6$, and $(1/6):3 = 1/18$ so $P(X_3=0) = 2/3+1/18, P(X_3=3) = 1/18$

Comment: @Walter I have some problems with $P(X_3=1) $ and $P(X_3=2)$

Comment: I'd suggest drawing the possible paths.

Comment: @Walter Oh, we can get $X_3=2$ if $X_2=2$ or $X_2=1$ so $P(X_3=2) = 1/18 + 1/18$ and similarly $X_3=1$ if $X_2=1$ or $X_2=2$ (then respectively $X_3=X_2$ with prob $1/3$ and $X_3=X_2 \pm 1$ with prob $1/3$ apply. ) Is that right?

Comment: Yes exactly right.